# Tkinter: multiple choice quiz app, can't change question (and other issues)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a multiple choice question app with tkinter but I'm having three problems that I can't solve by myself:

1. The question don't change, it stuck on the first question.
2. I have a file with all my questions (more then 50) what I'd like to do is select randomly only 10 of them from the list (five from easy_question list and 5 from the hard_question list).
3. Is there a way to save in an exel file the ten code of the question that where selected and to know what that person answered (wrong or right doesn't metter)? something like this:

```
         1  2  3 [...]
question 1e 3h 2e
answer   2  3  4
```

This is a simple version of my file with all my questions, options and correct answers:

```
easy_questions2=[
    "1e. Name?",
    "2e. Last name?",
    "3e. Birthdate?",
    "4e. Food?"
]

easy_options=[
    ['Marck', 'Mary','Joseph','John'],
    ['Smith', 'Hartnett','Pitt','Pacino'],
    ['June', 'October','November','April'],
    ['All', 'Fries','Pasta','Chicken']
]

easy_answers=[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    3
]

hard_questions2=[
    "1h. Number?",
    "2h. Word?",
    "3h. Hour?",
    "4h. Color?"
]

hard_options=[
    ['10', '11','21','55'],
    ['Book', 'Table','en','Pacino'],
    ['11', '21','24','18'],
    ['Yellow', 'Blue','Red','Green']
]

hard_answers=[
    3,
    4,
    1,
    2
]
```

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from questionslist import easy_questions2, easy_answers, easy_options
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
  


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)        

        self.q_no=0        

        self.display_title()
        self.display_question()
        
        self.opt_selected=tk.IntVar()
        
        self.opts=self.radio_buttons()
        
        self.display_options()
        
        self.buttons()
        
        self.data_size=len(question)
        
        self.correct=0


    def display_result(self):        
        wrong_count = self.data_size - self.correct
        correct = f"Correct: {self.correct}"
        wrong = f"Wrong: {wrong_count}"
        
        score = int(self.correct / self.data_size * 100)
        result = f"Score: {score}%"
        
        mb.showinfo("Result", f"{result}\n{correct}\n{wrong}")


    def check_ans(self, q_no):      
        if self.opt_selected.get() == answer[q_no]:
            return True


    def next_button(self):
        if self.check_ans(self.q_no):            
  
            self.correct += 1        

        self.q_no += 1
        
        if self.q_no==self.data_size:
            
            self.display_result()
            self.submit()
            
            self.destroy()
        else:
            self.display_question()
            self.display_options()



    def buttons(self):        
        next_button = tk.Button(self, text="Next",command=self.next_button, width=10)        

        next_button.pack(pady=50, side="bottom")    


    def display_options(self):
        val=0
        
        self.opt_selected.set(0)
        for option in options[self.q_no]:
            self.opts[val]['text']=option
            val+=1


    def display_question(self):        
        q_no = tk.Label(self, text=question[self.q_no], width=60)

        q_no.pack(padx=19, pady=31, anchor="w")   

    def radio_buttons(self):
        
        q_list = []
        
        while len(q_list) < 4:
            
            radio_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self,text=" ",variable=self.opt_selected,
            value = len(q_list)+1)
            
            q_list.append(radio_button)
            
            radio_button.pack(padx=19, anchor="w")            

        
        return q_list


    def submit(self):
        wb = load_workbook('D:\\Python\\quiz\\template.xlsx')
        sheet = wb.active

        sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value  = "first_name"
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value  = "correct"
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=4).value  = "wrong"  

        sheet.cell(row=2, column=3).value  = self.correct
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=4).value  = self.data_size - self.correct   
        
        excel_filename = "D:\\Python\\quiz\\" + "data" + ".xlsx"
        wb.save(excel_filename) 

question = easy_questions2
options = easy_options
answer = easy_answers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.title("Quiz")
    root.geometry('800x450')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: focus on one issue and provide a [mre] (read carefully what it says there)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the questions from a file (or more), you could use (suppose the file is a .txt and you've wrote a question per line):

```py
question_list = []

with open('filename.txt', 'r+') as question_file:
    lines = question_file.readlines()
    # Let's move the pointer of the file back to the start to resave the questions 
    # as we don't want to lose them.
    question_file.seek(0)
    question_file.truncate()

    for line in lines:
        question_list.append(line)    # Put each question at the end of the list.
        question_file.write(line)
```

Use this method to retrieve all the questions and answers from all your files and to put them into lists.

Now you should have a list for the easy questions and one for the hard questions, so, to pick a random question from one list you can use a specific function from the [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), `randint(a, b)` which is a function that return a value in between 'a' and 'b' ('a' and 'b' included). Try it this way:

```py
from random import randint

# You have a list of 25 hard question, let's call it hard_list
# and a list of 25 easy question, let's call it easy_list

# Now let's use our randint function to retrieve 10 random value between 0 and 24.
# As you haven't done any statement about how to choose the order of the questions, 
# I'll take the first five from the hards one and the last 5 from the easy,
# but you can do it in any way you want. 

# It may be a little tricky to manage the possibility of same random numbers to come out,
# surely there are better ways to do it, but this works fine.

random_questions = []        # Here I write the questions randomly chosen.
random_numbers = []          # I use this to take into account the random values.
i = 0                        # Our counter.

while i < 10:
    # If 5 questions have already been chosens, we change the list 
    # and clear the random values counter once.
    if i >= 5:
        if i == 5:
            random_numbers.clear()
        val = randint(0, 24)
        if val not in random_numbers:
            i += 1
            random_numbers.append(val)
            random_questions.append(easy_list[val])
    
    else:
        val = randint(0, 24)
        if val not in random_numbers:
            i += 1
            random_numbers.append(val)
            random_questions.append(hard_list[val])
```

Now, with your code, I see that the 'check_button' function doesn't check if the user have select an option or not, but maybe it's what you wanted, secondly, your button don't change the question because.. you're assigning a new Label to `q_no` (which, I suppose, is the number of questions answered so far)? You should assign the Label to another variable and update its text value each time the user click the button.

For example:

```py
self.question_label = tk.Label(self, text=question[self.q_no], ....)
self.question_label.pack(...)
```

And when the user press the button to the next question, you check if the answer is correct, then:

```py
self.q_no += 1

if self.q_no==(self.data_size + 1):
    #
    # Do what you want to do if that was the last question.
    #
else:
    self.question_label['text'] = question[self.q_no]
    #
    # Here change the value of the buttons with the answers.
    #
```

For the third question, what format do you exactly want? There are differences between .csv, .xlsx, .xlsb, etc. But for the conversion you can use the [pandas module](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

These methods need a specific type of object for the conversion, so be shure to format your data in that specific way before using them:
[to csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#writing-to-csv-format)    [to xlsx](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#writing-excel-files-to-disk). This is the class you can use as [data structure](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe).

From personal experience I know that you can format your datas as json to convert them to csv, but I'm not shure if it works for xlsx and other formats too.

Hope I've helped a little bit.